# USB C device termination without controller

Tags: usb-c

I was wondering about a minimal device (sink) design with USB C connector. In this case, where the device will only accept 5V and not further, I think a USB C controller is not mandatory. But I dont know how to terminate the CC1 and CC2 lines in order for the host (power provider) to know that the only available pdo level is 5V/2A. I have found this source but its not straight forward to me: https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/09/26/what_s_the_role_ofc-kQYe

I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Does [this link](https://community.cypress.com/docs/DOC-10779) help?

Comment: Not quite. While I get the CC connection part (and I assume is the same for other cc line), then I dont know to where is the second part connected on the connector (with Ra resistor). Besides, this table provides information on how can the device check the host capabilities. I kind of need the way around.

Comment: That's not how USB works. The host/source/downstream facing port says what it's capable of providing and the device/sink/upstream port chooses what it wants from what's available. If it only wants 5V it just doesn't ask for anything higher.

Comment: @Finbarr thanks for answer. This seems ok, as a device I can ask for anything. But the thing is i still dont know what capacity 5V charger was connected (or a PC).

Comment: Yes, you do - the value of pullup resistor Rp tells you. By measuring the voltage on your pulldown resistor Rd you can determine the DFP's capability.

Comment: Makes sense. But that on the other hand means that I need some kind of aware entity that can measure the voltage. Wont happen if my mcu is down because the battery is dead. I need an usb c controller right?

Comment: The default current at 5V is more than enough for you to power something to read the voltage. You only need the controller for higher voltage modes.

Comment: How does a pc host handle that? Assuming usb a to usb c cable. There is only 5V, but no 2A capacity?

Comment: How does a PC host handle what? CC1 and CC2 are only available on USB C ports.

Comment: Thats right- with usb c on the device side and usb a on the host side, how can the recognition be conducted?